# SQL-Injection prevention with if/else

Tags: php, android, mysql

I just thought about the safety of my php script and read a lot about sql injections.Now I have a question to save me from it.Is it right when my script doesnt accept characters like ***'*** , ***;*** or ***"*** ? Or I just catch this from my Android app ? So I just see the problem in these caracters. Am I right ? Or is there sth I dont see ? If not what would be the easiest way to safe it ?

Comment: Please be more specific. To prevent sql injections use prepared statements

Comment: I don't specificly ask HOW I prevent it.I just ask if I can reach the same solution with my idea. So dont accept characters like ' and " ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never check the string for injection, all you need to do is not concatenate the variable.

1. Use Prepared Statements.

a "example" in mysqli extract from http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-SQL-Injection-in-PHP

```
$name = $_GET['username'];

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE name=?")) {

    // Bind a variable to the parameter as a string. 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);

    // Execute the statement.
    $stmt->execute();

    // Get the variables from the query.
    $stmt->bind_result($pass);

   // Fetch the data.
   $stmt->fetch();

   // Display the data.
   printf("Password for user %s is %s\n", $name, $pass);

   // Close the prepared statement.
   $stmt->close();

}
```

read: http://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection

---

if your idea is check the variables for ' or " or ;, it's a hard endless job and in the end can solve by using PDO statment.